# Publishing eclipse jdt.core and jdt.ui to Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

I'm working on a plugin which supports language similar to Java and for that purpose I forked and modified eclipse.jdt.core and eclipse.jdt.ui plugins (just added some new operators and file extensions). Currently I have a custom installer for this plugins which works by simply replacing existing (original) eclipse jdt.core and jdt.ui plugins with my version and also modifies simpleconfigurator bundles.info file accordingly.

Is there a way to publish these plugins on Eclipse Marketplace so that somebody can download, install and update them easily?

I read all about publishing plugins but I'm not sure if these plugins are like the rest of them because they replace some core plugins inside eclipse.

Comment: Can't you just change the plugin ids so they don't clash with the org.jdt ones?

Comment: How would I specify which plugin to use for building projects? It's very important to use my plugin for building projects since I removed some things from the original plugin.

Comment: You seem to be trying to shortcut things here. If your language is not Java you should be defining a project nature for your language and a new wizard to create projects using that nature. The nature specifies what to use to build. There is no way I would personally ever install a modified version of the org.jdt plugins and I think that would apply to a lot of people.

Comment: I do have a project nature defined for my language. The project can contain both java files and files written in my language (which is Java with few more operators). To compile it the ecj.jar is used (of course I made one from modified plugin). Where would I specify which plugin to use to build my type of project?